# Subprocess.Popen only runs second time

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, popen

I have a boot controller which runs a `boot.py` file contained in each folder of each tool i am trying to deploy. I want my boot controller to run all of these boot files simultaneously. The config file has the tool names and the versions desired, which help to generate the path to the `boot.py`.

```
def run_boot():
    config_file = get_config_file()
    parse_config_file.init(config_file)
    tools = parse_config_file.get_tools_to_deploy()
    #tools is now a list of tool names
    top_dir = os.getcwd()
    for tool in tools:
        ver = parse_config_file.get_tool_version(tool).strip()
        boot_file_path = "{0}\\Deploy\\{1}\\{2}".format(os.getcwd(),tool,ver)
        try:
            subprocess.Popen('boot.py', shell=True,  cwd=boot_file_path)
        except:
            print ("{0} failed to open".format(tool))
        print(tool, boot_file_path)
        os.chdir(top_dir)
```

The first time i run this, the `print(tool, boot_file_path)` executes but the processes do not. the second time it is run the processes do open. I cannot find a reason for this.

Comment: Why do you run Python in a Python subprocess and why `shell=True` when you don't need a shell?

Comment: And why do you `chdir` to, effectively, the current directory? Perhaps your understanding of directories is really the problem here.

Comment: @tripleee when subprocess runs with `cwd` set to a value it switches the current working directory to that and then it can't find the others. Also, i don't understand what you mean by why do i run python in python subprocess? It is a script i need to run, what is the better way of doing this?

Comment: Use the fully-qualified path to "boot.py" instead of depending on the working directory. CMD can be configured more securely to ignore the working directory, which would break your script. If "boot.py" itself depends on the working directory, except in a few cases, it's likely that it's badly written. If it's your code, it's best to fix the problem at the source instead of hacking around it. In the bigger picture, there should be no reason to use the shell for this. Depending on the .py file association is fragile. Run `sys.executable` directly.

Comment: Also, paths should be joined via `os.path.join` instead of generic string formatting.

Comment: Running Python when you are already running Python is often an antipattern, though there are situations which actually demand this, too; that's why I'm asking why. The `import` statement allow s you to load Python code from another file and if ithat code is not specifically designed to depend on obeing run in a separate process, avoiding that is usually both more efficient and vastly more convenient and versatile for you as the programmer.

Comment: Windows is weird and sometimes horrible, but running a subprocess in another directory shouldn't change the parent's cwd even on Windows, to th best of my undertanding.

Comment: Are you aware that `Popen()` is asynchronous? You start the tools almost in parallel and not one after the other, so if a tool depends on some results of another tool you are in trouble.